# How can I change this loop to not use continue?

Tags: c++

I used the continue statement to make this simple program and got the desired output.

```
for(m=1;m<=3;m++)
{
   for(n=1;n<=2;n++)
   {
      if(m==n)
         continue;
      cout<<m<<" "<<n<<endl;
   }
}
```

output:

```
1  2
2  1
3  1
3  2
```

Now I want it without using the coninue statement.  Is there any way to make it?

Comment: What if I remove `if` also, along with `continue`? Would I get marks? :P See my solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution is even simpler. It doen't  use even `if`:

```
for(int m=1;m<=3;m++)
{
  for(int n=1;n<=2;n++)
  {
      m != n && (cout<<m<<" "<<n<<endl);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
1 2
2 1
3 1
3 2
```

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/rMSuK

Note that I'm not going to do this in production code, but for this particular problem, thinking of it as a puzzle, its good to have fun sometime, playing around with how C++ works. :D

Comment: Cool, but this belongs more to an obfuscation contest:)

Comment: @Peter: See my another solution.. I think that is better and can be applied in real scenario...

Comment: Cool! :) The one on callbacks was cool too! Didn't know these could be done in C++

Answer (score 5):

Simple as that:

```
if (m != n) {
  cout<<m<<" "<<n<<endl;
}
```

Comment: argh... I had to "enter more characters"... beat me by seconds!! :D

Comment: @Nim - Consider adding +2 to your reputation and it will become `6666`:)

Comment: @Nim - Make quickly four downvotes. But please don't start with me:)

Comment: @Petar, no good, that only does -1 point, I think I now have to do 8 downvotes today...

Comment: @Nim - Ah, correct it was -1. Yeah, wait for `gimme the codez` questions and downvote:)

Answer (score 4):

Another solution using callbacks:

```
void print(int m, int n)
{
  cout<<m<<" "<<n<<endl;
}
void noprint(int m, int n)
{ 
}

typedef void (*fn)(int,int);
fn calls[] = {noprint,print};
for(int m=1;m<=3;m++)
{
   for(int n=1;n<=2;n++)
   {
        calls[m!=n](m,n);
   }
}
```

Online demo : http://www.ideone.com/jLStA

Comment: that's something innovative !

Comment: @Nawaz: By evil, I meant kinda wicked/not-so-obvious/clever etc. Didn't mean this in a bad way.

Comment: I favourited this question just because of Nawaz's answer. Really cool!

Comment: @navaz you rock bro really i was finding something like this because IF is easiest way to do it but you did it as i want........@fredoverflow also on good way thanks...

Comment: @avirk: Are you running "exactly" the **same** code? Does it contain `main()`?  The complete code should look like this : http://www.ideone.com/jLStA

Comment: When m running on this code m getting 4 errors   1:Declaration terminated incorrectly.......2:Declaration syntax error..............3:Variable 'm' is initialized more than once....4:Declaration syntax error and these all are on the for(int m=1;m<=3;m++) loop.........what is wrong i cudn't ge

Comment: ya i was exactly missing the main() how can i forget about the main() which is the life of a program thanx.........and if m right you use the pointer with the array to call the methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (m != n)
{
  cout<...
}
```

....... need more characters...dammit

Answer (score 1):

Like this (I took the freedom to properly indent your code and use `std::` where appropriate):

```
for (m = 1; m <= 3; m++) {
    for (n = 1; n <= 2; n++) {
        if (m != n) {
            std::cout << m << " " << n << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 'Properly' being your particular style :)

Comment: @Nick: True, though using `std::` is general good practice, and same goes for `"\n"` unless you need to force a buffer clear (which seemed unlikely in this situation).

Comment: Didn't know that about std::endl - learn something new every day!

Comment: I don't know about the `"\n"`.  I'd say just the reverse: it's better to use `std::endl` unless you know you don't want to flush the buffer.  Especially for beginners: it can be very confusing when the program crashes and the buffer hasn't been flushed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not require an `if`:

```
for (int m = 1; m <= 3; ++m)
{
    for (int n = 1; n < m; ++n)
    {
        std::cout << m << " " << n << std::endl;
    }
    for (int n = m + 1; n <= 2; ++n)
    {
        std::cout << m << " " << n << std::endl;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I simply skip the `m` by not including it in the iteration :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply reverse the condition and put the rest of the code inside it.

As you tagged the question with C#, here's the C# code:

```
for(int m = 1; m <= 3; m++) {
  for(int n = 1; n <= 2; n++) {
    if (m != n) {
      Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", m, n);
    }
  }
}
```